# Exists a Java Map cache data structure?

Tags: java, dictionary, caching, java-8

I need to handle a Cached Map in my java application.
This is map is an always growing structure and the I need some method to remove old objects in the map when they are not used for a while.

Is there any existing Java map structure that implements this logic defining a maximum lifetime of the object in the map or some common library that implements this map?
I'm using Java8 and Java-Commons libraries.

Comment: Have a look at the Google Guava Cache implementations!

Answer (score 1):

If you can add external libraries you could use [guava](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache) or [Caffeine](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine)

Another option is to have a daemon thread that wakes up periodically and removes the untouched objects but I think is better to use an existing library.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as LRU cache.

```
static class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private int maxSize;

    private LRUCache(int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize, 0.75f, true);
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > maxSize;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LRUCache<Integer, Integer> cache = new LRUCache<>(2);
    cache.put(1, 1);
    cache.put(2, 2);
    cache.get(1);
    cache.put(3, 3);
    cache.get(1);
    cache.put(4, 4);
    cache.get(1);
    cache.put(5, 5);
    System.out.println(cache);
}
```

output:

```
{1=1, 5=5}
```

You can implement a removal strategy in `removeEldestEntry()`.